# How to unlock the extra content playing by yourself

Tags: game-boy-advance, zelda-link-to-the-past

My brother and I still have a copy of the GBA game The Legend of Zelda Link to the Past/Four Swords and we recently found out that there is bonus content for Link to the Past when one has beaten Four Swords. The only problem is, we don't know anyone else who has GBA Four Swords and a link cable.

So, is it possible to gain access to the extra content (such as the [Lumberjack's Brother's Riddle Quest](https://zeldawiki.org/Riddle_Quest)) either without beating Four Swords, or by (in some convoluted way) beating Four Swords solo?

Comment: I don't think that you can normally, but if you have the tools you should be able to hack the game into thinking that you beat Four Swords

Comment: You can still buy off-brand link cables if that's the issue. My sister and I got one and it worked. I don't remember the exact product though.